# Lost bitcoins - Multibit

Tags: blockchain, client, multibit

I have tried to pay an invoice via BitPay, the transaction was stuck at 'seen by one peer' and the BitPay invoice expired.

After closing and reopening multibit a few times, I decided to reset blockchain info as suggested in the multibit faq.

Well, this is what happened:

[image]

The transaction to BitPay doesn't even show anymore, but my coins are gone, how do I get them back ?

Comment: Before you do anything else, check whether you made the payment or not. Use blockexplorer or a similar authoritative tool.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz there is no information about the transaction to BitPay on Blockexplorer / Blockchain.info, but my coins are still not showing

Answer (score 1):

Exporting the private key, then importing it into a new wallet (still in MultiBit) recovered the missing bitcoins for me.

Comment: Per some recommendations I found elsewhere, I will try exporting my private key and using it in another client later today.  Will report back if this works.